# search time of unordered_map in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I have two different implementation of the same function

```
IPAddress UMNS::lookup(const HostName& name) const{
    auto it=ns.find(name);
    if(it!=ns.end()){
        return (*it).second;
    }
    return NON_EXISTING_ADDRESS;

}
```

and

```
IPAddress UMNS::lookup(const HostName& name) const{

    auto it=find_if(ns.begin(),ns.end(),
        [&name] ( const pair<HostName,IPAddress> &a){ return a.first==name;});
    bool found = it != ns.end();
    if ( found ){
        return (*it).second;
    }
    return NON_EXISTING_ADDRESS;

}
```

ns is an `unordered_map` but execution time of the two functions is not same.

First implementation gives this: 
Number of searches: 1000000 
Average search time (ms): 0.000373

Second implementation gives this: 
Number of searches: 1000000 
Average search time (ms): 24.9

Whats wrong with the second implementation?
Why can't I use find_if?

Comment: Because `find_if` is probably not taught to work with `unordered_map` and as such, just uses a linear search, compared to O(1) hash lookup. Also the question quality, ugh. :-D

Answer (score 6):

`find_if` knows nothing about whether or not the sequence it's searching is a container, let alone whether that container happens to offer an optimised way to do the same task. It will iterate over the sequence it's given, applying the predicate its given, which (for a large container) will be much slower than the hash-based lookup provided by the container's own `find` function.

Comment: but if it was a map and not an unorderd map would that make any difference?

Comment: @user2975699: `find_if` will still iterate over the map and apply its predicate; it still knows nothing about containers. `map::find` will (perhaps) be somewhat slower then `unordered_map::find` since it does a logarithmic-time search rather than a hash lookup.

Answer (score 3):

`std::find_if` is designed to work with any Input Iterators, which may come from other containers, such as `std::vector`. To find an element in generic containers like this, it needs to perform a linear search through all of the elements until it finds the one it's looking for. On the other hand, the `find` member of `std::unordered_map` is designed specifically for that container and is able to find elements in average constant time.

Answer (score 2):

`find_if` has to look through every entry in the map until it finds the one you're looking for, because it doesn't know that the second implementation is equivalent to the first one, because it can't see inside the predicate you give it (and the compiler can't optimize it).

Answer (score 1):

`find_if` is the least generic version that doesn't take advantage of the container internal structure or ordering. So it uses plain O(n) search. With the member `find` you are getting `O(1)` searches, since `unordered_map` is implemented as a hash table.